# Using EXPECT script with a $ in the password

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to set a variable in a Linux bash script which includes a `$` symbol, i.e. password is Gl@d1us$123 so `PASS="Gl@d1us\$123"`. I can preceed the `$` with a `\` and it works fine, but when it calls the EXPECT script the `$` symbol causes it to fail. I can enter the password directly into the EXPECT script using the `\` as before and it works fine, so it's just the process of passing the password variable between scripts that is causing me grief.

Main script:

```
echo  
echo  
USER=kendalla  
PASS="Gl@d1us\$123"  
DIR=/home/kendalla/scripts/Audit  

./get_hardware.expect $HOST $USER $PASS > $DIR/$HOST
```

get_hardware.expect script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
log_user 1  
log_file  /home/kendalla/scripts/Audit/HOST  
set HOST [lrange $argv 0 0]  
set USER [lrange $argv 1 1]  
set PASS [lrange $argv 2 2]  
spawn ssh -q -l $USER $HOST  
expect "$USER@rebehc01's password:"  
send "Gl@d1us\$123\r"    ;#(This works)  
send $PASS               ;#(This doesn't work)
```

All help appreciated.

Thanks

Andy.

Comment: Show some code. It can be readily solved.

Comment: Code appended as requested.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
./get_hardware.expect $HOST $USER $PASS > $DIR/$HOST .
```

In shell scripting you always want to quote your variables, unless you understand precisely when to not quote them.

```
./get_hardware.expect "$HOST" "$USER" "$PASS" > "$DIR/$HOST" .
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. `./get_hardware.expect "$HOST" "$USER" "$PASS" > "$DIR/$HOST"`  and  expect "$USER@$HOST's password:"
send "$PASS\r"
expect ">"

Comment: print out the value of $PASS in the expect script. What is it there?

Comment: I changed the expect script lrange to lindex and it works fine as I originally wrote it. thanks for your help anyway.